# How to translate the term "capacity expansion models" (economics) to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

How to translate the term "capacity expansion models" (economics) to Spanish?

The translation seems to be "modelos de expansión de capacidad" but it does not make sense in the context.

I'm reading an article about mathematical models formulations.

The sentence is as follows:

> The first model assumes a perfect, competitive equilibrium. It is very similar to the traditional "capacity expansion models" even if its economic interpretation is different. The second model (open-loop Cournot game) extends the Cournot model to include investments in new generation "capacities".

It is from the article *Generation capacity expansion in imperfectly competitive restructured electricity markets.* (Murphy et al. 2005).

Comment: I don't know much about economics, but I found an article about Cournot in wikipedia en español. That referenced an alternative, the [competencia de Bertrand](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competencia_de_Bertrand) which looks like another imperfect competition model. Maybe something in the article refers to capacity expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to "capacity investment," or *inversión en capacidad*. 
*Capacity* refers to how much electricity a plant is capable of producing.  Apparently, earlier, *capacity* was assumed to be fairly fixed when setting up and solving the linear programming problem (a type of optimization).  What happens if capacity is allowed to vary significantly?  In other words, if we make it a fundamental variable?  It looks like “capacity expansion models” allow for this.

Thus your phrase could be expressed as

**modelos con expansión en capacidad**

or

**modelos con capacidad expansible**

Here's an article in Spanish which talks about *inversión en capacidad* in a hydroelectric context: http://tesis.pucp.edu.pe/repositorio/handle/123456789/5928

I glanced at the abstract and it looked helpful.  I'd suggest looking at the full text.  Maybe there will be a helpful reference.

Also, since [Murphy and Smeers](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/opre.1050.0211), and the authors they cite, [Massé and Gibrat](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.3.2.149), appear to have been thinking about these concepts in French, it could be helpful to check how authors writing in French have expressed this and related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT after reading [Wikipedia's article in economic models](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_econ%C3%B3mico), there isn't an established term for that. Which was to be expected, given that even the author is using quotes to denote that "capacity expansion models" is an *ad hoc* name that they just gave to a class of similar models.

Given that there are other models with names such as [*Modelo de telaraña*](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Modelo_de_telara%C3%B1a), *[Modelo de crecimiento de Solow](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_crecimiento_de_Solow)*, [*Modelo de competencia perfecta*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competencia_perfecta), etc. I don't see why *modelos de expansión de la capacidad* wouldn't make sense.

Maybe ***modelos basados en la expansión de la capacidad*** seems better to you?

Answer (score -2):

The actual order of the words in Spanish when translating that would be 
: 
"**Modelos de capacidad de expansión**"

I'm not an expert on the topic you are referring to but... I hope that by having the right order it helps you find the alternative and technical terminology of the topic.

:) good luck!

Comment: This seems at variance with the other answers. Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: Spanish is one of my native languages, you can tell right away when something it's not translated correctly because it just makes no sense at all... Spanish and German are very specific.

Comment: @kam - Unfortunately, just going through the elements of the term in rote order doesn't always work.  It's best to check by thinking a bit about what was intended when the phrase was coined, and then think about how best to express this in the target language.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  if it doesn't help you find what you are looking for move to another answer, but at this point I'm not sure if you want a translation or an actual paper about the topic en Español.

Comment: @Kam - A thorough approach takes actual papers about the topic in Spanish into account.  But first one has to take a look at actual papers about the topic in English, to understand the term and the context.